# How can I associate a string with a particular array?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, append

I need to check a series of arrays for a value, and then if the value is within range, append an array of strings with a name for each array that passes the check.  For example, in the code below, I'd like to end up with "First Array" being appended to lensLibrary, since it contains spherePower.

How do I associate a string with each array, to be used as a name to display to a user? I tried a switch, using a different case for each array passed as an argument, but that failed, as did if statements.

```
let arrayA : [Float] = [1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0]  // "First Aray"

let arrayB : [Float] = [5.5,6.0,6.5,7.0,7.5,8.0,8.5,9.0,9.5]  // "Second Array"

var lensLibrary : [String] = []


func arrayContains(array: [Float], powerD : Float) {

    var lensName : String!

    if array.minElement() < powerD && powerD < array.maxElement() {

        lensLibrary.append( /* Name of Array that was checked  */  )

    }


 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    spherePower = 4.5

    // Check if spherePower is in each array, and add the name of the array to lensLibrary if it is present
    arrayContains(arrayA, powerD: spherePower)
    arrayContains(arrayB, powerD: spherePower)

    }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't add "the name of the array" to `lensLibrary`; `lensLibrary` is an array of Floats, not an array of names. You cannot insert a String (like "FirstArray") into an array of Floats. And why would you even want to? How would the user even know about these names?

Comment: Also, your code in no way looks to see if `powerD` is _in_ the array. I hope you don't think it does. It doesn't.

Comment: My apologies, the float type was an error in copying over the code, it's simplified and not copied and pasted over.  As for the checking, yes, I'm aware that, as written, it checks range only.  I have another function that checks to see if it's actually in the array, but I omitted it for simplicity.  What I'm trying to do is create an array of strings that will contain only the "names" of the arrays that pass the check.  What I'm asking is, how do I assign a name to each array, so that when an array passes the check(s), it's name can be appended to lensLibrary and displayed to the user?

Comment: Well, it doesn't _have_ a name. The strings after the comments are just comments you are making; they are not something in the program itself. The usual way to associate a string name with an object is a dictionary: the key is the name and the value is the object. So you could start with a dictionary of `[String : [Float]]` - the keys are strings (the names), and the values are arrays-of-floats (like your `arrayA` and `arrayB`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is start with a Dictionary of `[String : [Float]]`. The string key is the name; the `[Float]` is the float array. Your dictionary has two entries. There is no longer `arrayA` and `arrayB` at all; just the dictionary. In `viewDidLoad`, cycle through the key-value pairs of the dictionary. For each key-value pair, if the value (the array) contains the power being sought, put the key into the array-of-names.